# Have a function or class to store local variables that are parsed from yaml file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyyaml

I have a few lines of code that will open a yaml file and parse some values and store them in local variables in PYTHON.

**config.yml:**

```
mysql:
  host: localhost
  database: myDatabase
  user: root
  password: root
```

and my code so far:

```
import yaml
with open("config.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)

host = cfg["mysql"]["host"]
database = cfg["mysql"]["database"]
user = cfg["mysql"]["user"]
password = cfg["mysql"]["password"]
```

**I was wondering if there is a way I can store this in a neat function, and more importantly, call each variable from another function.**

Something like:

```
def parse_config():
    <code> 

def main():
    password = parse_config()
```

**Also, would it be better to have this in a SEPERATE class?**

Comment: In your example you seem to be setting all `mysql` information to a variable called `password`. There is no way for a called function to know what it is being assigned to.

Comment: Your code will through an error, as `cfg = yaml.load()` is not properly indented. The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is XML based and looks completely different from the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) format, which is what you have. The [recommended file extension](http://yaml.org/faq.html) for *YAML* files has been  `.yaml` since 2006.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this as a class and then you don't need to access the file every time.

```
import yaml

class MyYaml():

    def __init__(self):
        with open("config.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
            cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)

            self.host = cfg["mysql"]["host"]
            self.database = cfg["mysql"]["database"]
            self.user = cfg["mysql"]["user"]
            self.password = cfg["mysql"]["password"]

my_yaml = MyYaml()

print(my_yaml.host)
print(my_yaml.database)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you will access the file every time.

```
def parse_config(param: str):
    with open("config.yml", 'r') as ymlfile:
        cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)
        return(cfg["mysql"][param])

password = parse_config("password")
```